# decrease one in the value of the column inside loop laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I have this loop:

```
foreach($cart as $product){
    if($product->pivot->coupon_id){

        $coupon = Coupon::find($product->pivot->coupon_id);

        $coupon->update(['max_uses'=> $coupon->max_uses-1]);
    }
}
```

What I want is decrement from coupon `max_uses` column by 1, but right now it gets decremented by 2 because there is a loop before it.

How can I avoid the loop and decrease just one!

Comment: why do you need the loop if you only want to do something with 1 item? and the model has a `decrement` method

Comment: @lagbox long story but in short I have coupon_id column as pivot for each product in cart so I can control the coupon that's come from user and I can not put it in carts table since my app e-commerce for multi store! so user may have two or there coupon in one cart purchase operation! + since my project is multi-store I need this loop for collect the product for each store etc etc ..

Comment: well if you think you **need** the loop then you can't avoid it so I don't understand the point of your question

Comment: @lagbox simply there is a column in coupons table called (max_uses) int like coupon abc has just 10 times to use, and I need for each order decrement(decrease) one from the max_uses!

Comment: To do that, i use DB::raw $coupon->update(['max_uses'=> DB::raw('max_uses'-1)]);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach($cart as $key => $product){
  if($key == 0){
   if($product->pivot->coupon_id){

    $coupon = Coupon::find($product->pivot->coupon_id);

    $coupon->update(['max_uses'=> $coupon->max_uses-1]);
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, a good answer should explain **what** the code does and **how** it helps